# Yolo object detection webcam opencv error

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda, yolo

I am trying object detection using yolo
following tutorial https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/

I want to use Webcam to do realtime detection

so i configured Makefile OPENCV = 1

and tried to make again

I get following error

```
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -DOPENCV -c ./src/gemm.c -o obj/gemm.o
Package opencv was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `opencv.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'opencv' found
In file included from ./src/utils.h:5:0,
                 from ./src/gemm.c:2:
include/darknet.h:25:43: fatal error: opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:85: recipe for target 'obj/gemm.o' failed
make: *** [obj/gemm.o] Error 1
```

I have cv installed on Anaconda

```
Python 2.7.14 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Dec  7 2017, 17:05:42) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>> print(cv2.__version__)
3.4.1
>>>
```

Comment: `Perhaps you should add the directory containing opencv.pc
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable` So just do `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/my/additional/config`

Comment: what does this my/addational/config ? can u explain steps in detail I am new to opencv

Comment: Probably related issues: [https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/10963](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/10963), [https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/issues/518](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/issues/518), ... Try to downgrade to OpenCV 3.4.0.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I followed your step I get a long error : ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: fatal error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [libdarknet.so] Error 1

Comment: how did you build opencv? If you built it correctly you should be able to use `sudo ldconfig` after installation to properly add it to pkg-config path.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error as you.
when I try to follow this tutorial to install opencv3.4 manually,re-make and it works. But remember the version of OpenCV can't over 3.4.0, I tried 4.0.0 but failed.
https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d2/de6/tutorial_py_setup_in_ubuntu.html

My OS is Ubuntu16.04, hope to help you.